# Element is not displayed in Internet Explorer using Protractor framework

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

I am using protractor framework for end-to-end testing. For browser i need to user Internet explorer. the problem is click is not working in internet explorer. same test case I use for Chromedriver. And it runs perfectly. But whenever I try to run this with internet explorer i got the following error. I saw the elemt is present when direct to the inspect page.

```
    Failed: Element is not displayed
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'NB132', ip: '10.0.75.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
WebDriverError: Element is not displayed
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'NB132', ip: '10.0.75.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

My configuration for protractor is

```
multiCapabilities:[
    {
        'browserName': 'internet explorer',
        version:11,
        'se:ieOptions' : {
            nativeEvents: false,
            ignoreZoomSetting: true,
            ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true,
            enablePersistentHover: true,

        },
        unhandledPromptBehavior : 'accept'
    }
    ],

  jvmArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=./node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/IEDriverServer3.141.0.exe'],
```

Comment: Can you post the html and the selector you are trying to use?
Keep in mind that it must be visible to the user. If you open dev tools and hover over the element, it should tell you the dimensions that are actually visible.